# leetcode question search 2d matrix Question 74

Tags: python

```
class Solution(object):
    def out(self,matrix,target):
        m1=len(matrix)
        m=m1//2
        print('m value is'+str(m))
        n=len(matrix[m])
        print('n value is'+str(n))
        if matrix[m][0]>target:
            print('it came to 1st clause')
            self.out(matrix[0:m],target)
        elif matrix[m][0]<target and matrix[m][n-1]<target:
            print('it came to 2nd clause')
            self.out(matrix[m+1:m1],target)
        elif matrix[m][0]<target and matrix[m][n-1]>target:
            print('it came to final clause')
            for c in matrix[m]:
                print(c)
                if c==target:
                    print('true')
                    return True
        return False
    def searchMatrix(self, matrix, target):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if(len(matrix)==0):
            return False
        return self.out(matrix,target)
```

I don't know why I am getting answer as False for the `Input([[1,3,5,7],[10,11,16,20],[23,30,34,60]],3)` can you please look into this when I run the solution it is going to elif loop and printing True but returning False.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning while recursing, whenever you use recursion remember to return the value:

```
class Solution(object):
    def out(self,matrix,target):
        m1=len(matrix)
        m=m1//2
        print('m value is'+str(m))
        n=len(matrix[m])
        print('n value is'+str(n))
        if matrix[m][0]>target:
            print('it came to 1st clause')
            return self.out(matrix[0:m],target)       ### <- return recursion
        elif matrix[m][0]<target and matrix[m][n-1]<target:
            print('it came to 2nd clause')
            return self.out(matrix[m+1:m1],target)    ### <- return recursion
        elif matrix[m][0]<target and matrix[m][n-1]>target:
            print('it came to final clause')
            for c in matrix[m]:
                print(c)
                if c==target:
                    print('true')
                    return True
        return False
    def searchMatrix(self, matrix, target):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if(len(matrix)==0):
            return False
        return self.out(matrix,target)
```